# How can I select files using file importer in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to select file from **FileImporter** in SwiftUI, but i can't select files

[image]

this is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var isShowing = false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Button {
            isShowing.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("documents")
        }.fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.item]) { result in
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let Fileurl):
                print(Fileurl)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }     
        }
    }  
}
```

how can i fix that?

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Why are you using `.item` as content type, what happens if use a more specific content type?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i use .item because i want to select all type of files

Comment: I understand that but are you sure `.item` can be used for that? This is why I asked if you could try with some other type like `.plainText` to see if that works or if you have some other issue. Basic troubleshooting in other words.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i tried this but my problem still not fixed, which privacies should i write in info.plist for using document files?

Comment: So you couldn't select a text file?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No , i can just select folders

Comment: @JoakimDanielson 
i found my problem , i can't select file because i have third party library in my app(in another project i tried and i can select files) , you know how can i fix this?

Comment: Of course not since I have no idea what that library is and how it affects the import functionality. This is something you need to research yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update Xcode 14.2**

since Xcode version 14.2 this bug **fixed** and file importer let to select all files if use **allowedContentTypes: [.item]**

> Finally it's possible to select all files with one click in the simulator.

[image]

**Old Answer - for Xcode 14.1 or lower**

After a very long search, I found the answer to this question

It is not possible to select a file in the simulator But if you need to select files to test your code you can do this steps

**Step 1:** Hold on file

**Step 2:** When the file pops up, click on it again

With these two steps you can select your file

Answer (score 4):

Here what you looking for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button {
                isShowing.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("documents")
            }
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.item], allowsMultipleSelection: true, onCompletion: { results in
                
                switch results {
                case .success(let fileurls):
                    print(fileurls.count)
                    
                    for fileurl in fileurls {
                        print(fileurl.path)
                    }
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
                
            })

        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: my problem is that i can't select files (in the screen shot you can see this)

Comment: look my pic in answer, that is how you can select.

Comment: All files and folders turn gray when I select that button

Comment: i found my problem , i can't select file because i have third party library in my app(in another project i tried and i can select files) , you know how can i fix this?

Comment: No, I do not know. I just answered your current question.

Comment: For me the three dots icon is missing... I cannot see it... Is there something I am doing wrong? When I set the multi selection to "false" then I see the three dots but "select" is now missing